Is inner membrane of mitochondria less permeable than outer membrane?
Given below are two statements:
Statement I: Mitochondria and chloroplasts both double membranes bound organelles.
Statement II: Inner membrane of mitochondria is relatively less permeable, as compared chloroplast.
In the light of the above statements, choose the mis appropriate answer from the options given below:
(1) Both Statement I and Statement II are incorrect.
(2) Statement I is correct but Statement Il is incorrect.
(3) Statement I is incorrect but Statement Il is correct.
(4) Both Statement I and Statement II are correct.
One more thing to note is that answer will be based on this statement from textbook which itself is vague-
"Like mitochondria, the chloroplasts are also double membrane bound. Of the two, the inner chloroplast membrane is relatively less permeable."
Plz answer me based on facts and also based on the statement I have copy pasted from textbook.

Welcome to SE Biology. Please do us the courtesy of finishing the [Tour] and learning about how this site works. In particular you should note that "Homework questions are off-topic on Biology unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see our homework policy."
